# PHP Get dates from week

Tags: php, date

How to get the dates for perticular week using for loop(7days)

for example,

```
$date_start = '2012/09/03';
```

i want to get the feature dates ie. `'2012/09/04','2012/09/05','2012/09/06'...'2012/09/08'` for a week.

I got the code, but it is taking long time to execute:

while(strtotime($start_date)<= strtotime($end_date)){}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the solution you can do it like

```
$date_start = '2012/09/03';

$end_date = date ("Y/m/d", strtotime("+7 day", strtotime($date_start)));

while (strtotime($date_start) <= strtotime($end_date)) {
        echo $date_start = date ("Y/m/d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($date_start)));         

    }
```

here is live working example

[Demo](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/in4-gjx)

Or just visit the link .. hope it helps

[php future Date in loop](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2009/php-loop-through-dates-from-date-to-date-with-strtotime-function/)

Comment: but, it taking long time to display. i need only the loop between the day. i.e 04,05,06...

Comment: start and end dates for 1week

Comment: hi,hameed it starting from 04th and ends with 9th. i need from 03 to 08th

Comment: You have an arbitrary date and you want the beginning of the week for that date and end of week with all the dates in between? If so, what is Start of week, Sunday or Monday?

Comment: hi, tigrang start week is monday and end is sataurday

Answer (score -1):

```
$date = '2012/09/03'; // Start date
$date_seconds = strtodste($date); // Unix-time format (in seconds from 01.01.1970)
$week_seconds = 3600 * 24 * 7; // Second in week = 604800

while(true){

    $date_seconds += $week_seconds;

    var_dump(date('Y/d/m', $date_seconds));

}
```